# Dynamically loading templates in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like the ability to load templates dynamically without explicitly specifying the template.

As an example:

```
<template name="foo">
</template>
```

where 'foo' is the template, I would like the ability to load it dynamically by calling some method:

```
Meteor.render(Meteor.loadTemplate('foo'));
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Meteor 0.9.x New API**

Dan Dascalescu pointed out Meteor now has built-in dynamic templates! This is nice because you do not need to include the extra code as seen in previous versions.

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=template [data=data] }}
```

**For Meteor 0.8.x Legacy**

Dynamic Template *Without* Data: Boris Kotov's updated Blaze (0.8.0) answer is on the right track (taken from the latest docs), but it doesn't work as-is for me. I got the following to work:

```
{{> dynamicTemplate name=myDynName}}

<template name="dynamicTemplate">
    {{#with chooseTemplate name}}
        {{> template}}
   {{/with}}
</template>

Template.dynamicTemplate.chooseTemplate = function (name) {
    return { template: Template[name] };
};
```

I hope there is a simpler solution, but I needed to wrap the Template in a JSON as shown. Maybe this will help someone else to move forward.

Dynamic Template *With* Data: If you have and want data to be dynamic, be sure to make a helper method that can react. Be sure to do a Session.set() somewhere to see the effect.

```
// Inside "myContainingTemplate"
{{> dynamicTemplateWithData name=myDynName data=myDataHelper}}

<template name="dynamicTemplateWithData">
    {{#with chooseTemplate name}}
        {{#with ../data}}
            {{> ..}}
        {{/with}}
    {{/with}}
</template>

Template.dynamicTemplateWithData.chooseTemplate = function (name) {
    return Template[name];
};

Template.myContainingTemplate.helpers({
    myDataHelper: function () {
        Session.get('myReactiveKey');
    }
});
```

Comment: The API has changed in the meantime. Now the recommended method is to use http://docs.meteor.com/#template_dynamic

Answer (score 37):

Here's how to dynamically render templates, as of Meteor 0.9.4 - 1.0. All other answers were obsolete at the time of this writing.

Let's say you're editing a bunch of records, or creating a new one, and want to render either the `update` template, or the `new` template, based on some Session variables.

There are two ways to do this:

1) This is the **officially recommended method for Meteor 0.9.4 or newer** - it uses [`Template.dynamic`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic):

```
<template name="records">
  {{> Template.dynamic template=whichOne}}
</template>

<template name="recordUpdate">
  ...
</template>

<template name="recordNew">
  ...
</template>

Template.records.helpers({
  whichOne: function () {
    return Session.get('edit') ? 'recordUpdate' : 'recordNew'
    // note that we return a string - per http://docs.meteor.com/#template_dynamic
  }
});
```

2) This works in various Meteor versions, but isn't recommended officially because it's unclear that the template is chosen dynamically:

```
<template name="records">
  {{> whichOne}}
</template>

{{! Note how "whichOne" is indistinguishable from a constant template name... }}
{{  ...like "recordUpdate" or "recordNew" below. }}

<template name="recordUpdate">
  ...
</template>

<template name="recordNew">
  ...
</template>

Template.records.helpers({
  whichOne: function () {
    return Session.get('edit') ? Template.recordUpdate : Template.recordNew
    // note that we return a Template object, not a string
  }
});
```

To pass a data context to the template, use:

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=whichOne data=myData}}
```

Comment: This is now the most popular answer, but I recommend showing how to optionally pass in data to the scope. {{> Template.dynamic template=whichOne data=myData}}

Comment: Excellent - +1 for the fact you took time to write updating us with current information as Meteor evolves "versionally".  I found myself using #1 approach.  I was satisfied after getting debug reports as the errors were what I expected and is not out of proportion compared to thousands and thousands debug reports I have seen.  However, approach #2 returned less detailed reports and some errors still prevailed - possibly because (I am not sure but, suspected) it's "too dynamic" in between the process when involving "middle-processing". Thank you for the updated information.

Comment: @Turbo @DanDascalescu :: about the line for passing data optionally, the `data=myData` snippet: is that `key=value`?

Comment: @Faron: it's the entire data context. See http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic

Comment: @Faron The parameter name is specifically data and the value will become the template's this context. myData is an object that is accessible in the chosen template.

Answer (score 7):

You have found Meteor.render but what you are missing is the template loading.
In the docs it mentions that you can call Template.foo() to return the HTML for a template.

http://docs.meteor.com/#template_call

Putting that together you access the template foo or any other using bracket access so:

```
var templateName = "foo";
var fragment = Meteor.render( function() {
    return Template[ templateName ](); // this calls the template and returns the HTML.
});
```

Then fragment is your Reactive fragment, so that your template can continue to receive live updates. Your fragment now needs placing in the web page (I use jQuery, so this example does as well):

```
$("#htmlnode").html( fragment );
```

$("#htmlnode") is just a node in your DOM where you want the template rendered. And you now have the rendered content in your web page.

Comment: This worked for me with some minor changes. Because I had surrounded the elements in my template by div tags, using the above code rendered an undefined fragment. Calling Meteor.render( Template[ templateName ] ) instead resolved this issue.

Comment: Just in case anyone's having trouble with the code as is, you may need to check if the template is accessible first with "if (Template[templateName])" before calling it.

Comment: Quite right Dave. I tend to print a message to the console if a template doesn't exist so that I know straight away if I have used the wrong name etc..

Comment: i wish this worked with returning an HTML string, rather than a documentFragment so that you can let Meteor's Spark render the template, i.e. within another template. Anyone know how to do that? returning a document fragment as a template helper does not work, and either does returning the string generated in the function supplied to render(). It has all the landmark, label stuff.

Comment: I think my answer below might help you @faceyspacey.com

Comment: Meteor.render, if you want to pass values to the template, should be written like this:

Meteor.render(function(){
    return Template.myTemplate({foo: "bar"});
   })

Comment: Meteor.render() no longer exists. Everyone looking here should probably go read this first: http://docs.meteor.com/#ui , see UI.render and UI.insert

Comment: This answer and the comments were obsoleted by Meteor 0.9.4 - please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26421763/1269037) and https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2836 regarding direct assignments to `Template.foo`.

Comment: This helped me. As of 1.2.1 I think this is needed. `return Template[ tName ].renderFunction();` (in a helper.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm just doing it like this, no jQuery required:

**EDITED**

```
Template.mainContent.showContentFromRouter = function() {
    return Template[Meteor.Router.page()]();
};
```

In this case I'm using the Meteor Router, and return whatever template that I choose to (from the Router), but you could just do this:

```
Template.mainContent.showDynamicContent = function() {
    return Template['someTemplateYouveDefined']();
};
```

Comment: When I try this the markup shows up on the page as a string. How do you get around this?

Comment: You add an extra {} around the {{showContentFromRouter}}-thing in the template. Like this: {{{showContentFromRouter}}}. This HTML-escapes the string. @Samo

Comment: the problem with this solution is that the template is generated in the memory over and over again, as long as the showDynamicContent function is called. is there a way to remove the template from the memory? i testet this with rendering 1000+ sub templates and removing them a few times back and forth

Comment: @frozeman, I did't really understand what you mean. Can you test it with my solution? -> #2 Answer. Or tell use, how to test it =)

Comment: This is *very* obsolete - please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26421763/1269037) and https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2836 regarding direct assignments to `Template.foo`.

Answer (score 2):

Update for blaze:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#templatefoo-is-not-a-function-and-does-not-return-a-string

Dynamically render a template with a given data context

Old:

```
{{dynamicTemplate name="templateName" data=dataContext}}

Template.foo.dynamicTemplate = function (opts) {
  return Template[opts.name](opts.data);
};
```

New: (Notably, in Blaze, keyword arguments to inclusion or block helpers are bundled into a single object which becomes the new data context)

```
{{> dynamicTemplate name="templateName" data=dataContext}}

<template name="dynamicTemplate">
  {{#with chooseTemplate name}}
    {{#with ../data}}  {{! original 'data' argument to DynamicTemplate}}
      {{> ..}}         {{! return value from chooseTemplate(name) }}
    {{/with}}
  {{/with}}
</template>

Template.dynamicTemplate.chooseTemplate = function (name) {
  return Template[name];
}
```

By the way, I don't really played with it, but this is what I took from the new blaze docs. So I think it should be the way to do it ;)

Comment: what do you mean with context?? id did you mena name="templateNAME"?

Comment: Yes, correct. Id in this case is the identifier of the template or the name of the template. The context variable is what you put in your template. Hope it helps.

Comment: How or where do you set id and context?

Comment: cristian, I updated my answere to the new 0.8.0 version.

Comment: This is obsolete - please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26421763/1269037) and https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2836 regarding direct assignments to `Template.foo`.

Answer (score 0):

**Meteor 0.8.x Legacy**

Using [Joc's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12986397/792406) answer as a guide, 
I've achieved similar using http://docs.meteor.com/#template_call, but using a helper instead, as suggested by the docs:

> When called inside a template helper, the body of Meteor.render, or other settings where reactive HTML is being generated, the resulting HTML is annotated so that it renders as reactive DOM elements

My client.js looks a bit like this:

```
Template.myPageTemplate.helpers({
  dynamicTemplate: function() {
    // conditional logic can be added here to determine which template to render
    return Template.myDynamicTemplate();
  }
});
```

and my html looks like this:

```
<template name="myPageTemplate">
  <h1>My Template</h1>
  {{{dynamicTemplate}}}
</template>

<template name="myDynamicTemplate">
  <h1>My Dynamic Template</h1>
</template>
```

Comment: This is obsolete - please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26421763/1269037)

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze

```
{{> post}}

Template.foo.helpers({
  post: function () {
    return Template[this.postName];
  }
});
```

Template inclusions now search the namespace of helpers and data for template objects, so it's easy to programmatically choose which template to use. This is a powerful feature, and will allow patterns like assigning one template as a helper of another so that it can be overridden.

Comment: Thanks! I've removed the deprecated code. (Still this is not the recommended solution.)

Answer (score -1):

Based on hillmark's answer, this is the easiest it could get:

```
Template.main.template = function() {
  if (some_condition) {
    return Template.A();
  } else {
    return Template.B();
  }
};
```

With the corresponding .html

```
<body>
    {{> main}}
</body>

<template name="main">
    {{{template}}}
</template>

<template name="A">
    <h1>Template A</h1>
</template>

<template name="B">
    <h1>Template B</h1>
</template>
```

**Edit**
Doesn't work in Meteor 0.8.0

Comment: This is obsolete - please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26421763/1269037) and https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2836 regarding direct assignments to `Template.foo`.

Answer (score -1):

for me the easiest way was to just create a function get_dynamic_template, so something like:

```
var a= get_dynamic_template(template_name,data);
```

which returns what can be rendered as a normal variable {{a}}

The code for this function is quite simple:

```
var get_dynamic_template = function(template_name,data)
{

      return function(){
        return new Handlebars.SafeString(
          UI.toHTML(
               Template[template_name].extend({data: function () { return data; }}))
          );
      };

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This would handl dynamic templates both with and without data: 
(requires Blaze/ Meteor 0.8)

```
{{> dynamicTemplate name=templateName}}

<template name="dynamicTemplate">
    {{#with chooseTemplate name }}
        {{#if ../data}}
            {{#with ../data }}
                {{> .. }}
            {{/with}}
        {{else}}
            {{> this}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/with}}
<template name="dynamicTemplate">
```

template javascript:

```
Template.dynamicTemplate.chooseTemplate = function (name) {
    return Template[name];
};
```

Comment: This is obsolete - please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26421763/1269037).