# Meteor Page Re-rendering with Backbone router

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-framework, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm trying to create a blog application with Meteor. In this blog there is the main page where visitors will simply read the posts, and another section where it would be the 'admin' panel where I can edit posts. I'm trying to utilize the handlebars Template helpers but I'm not sure where I got it wrong. I'm also a amateur developer and trying to learn the Meteor framework better. My code is as such:

**blog.html**

```
<head>
  <title>Jeff Lam Tian Hung</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Jeff Lam Tian Hung</h1>
  <a href="/" class="main">Main Page</a>
  <a href="/admin" class="admin">Admin</a>
  {{> content}}
</body>

<template name="content">
  {{#if currentPage "blog"}}
    {{#each posts}}
      <h2>{{Title}}</h2>
      <p>{{Body}}</p>
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}

  {{#if currentPage "admin"}}
    <h2>{{admin}}</h2>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

**blog.js**

```
// Declaration of Collections
Posts = new Meteor.Collection("Posts");

// Helper variable is for pages
// TODO: changing this var will change the
// page but now how to rerender the page?
var page = "blog";

// Declaration of Template Reactivity Variables
Template.content.currentPage = function (type) {
  return page === type;
};
Template.content.posts = function () {
  return Posts.find({}, {sort: {Date: 1}});
};
Template.content.admin = function () {
  return "This will render admin section";
};

// Router for Pages
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "":      "main",
    "admin": "admin"
  },
  main: function () {
    page = "blog";
  },
  admin: function () {
    page = "admin";
  }
});

var BlogRouter = new Router;

Meteor.startup(function () {
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});
```

**publish.js (server-side code only)**

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection("Posts");
```

The page would render the blog posts with the above code, but when I access localhost:3000/admin the page variable is set to 'admin' as coded, but the page/template doesn't re-render itself to display the 'Admin' text.

However, if I were to set the var page = 'admin' and refresh the app, the page rerenders the admin message just fine. I'm not sure if I'm using the handlebars template helpers correctly to do this sort of 'one-page template refresh with routing'. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your variable 'page' is not reactive, just a plain JavaScript variable. It has no way of notifying Meteor of changes.

When I started using Meteor I put the page 'code' into a Session variable for similar purposes and this will trigger your page updates. For example:

```
// Declaration of Template Reactivity Variables
Template.content.currentPage = function (type) {
    return Session.equals("page", type);
};
```

and in your Router:

```
...
Session.set("page", "admin");
…
```

(Although you probably want to put the Session.set bit in it's own function)

Because Session variables are reactive in the Meteor framework and will notify when changed.

Comment: Thanks! There is one slight mistake though: instead of "return Session.get("page")" it should be "return Session.equals("page", type)" to complete the function. But you point me on the right track so thank you so very much!

Comment: Ha, yes, sorry, was thinking of my own code for that but yes the theory is the same. Saying that I don't use this method so much now as it requires lots of 'if' statements which can get quite cluttered as your site grows and use a more dynamic method now.

Comment: Thx for that. Maybe i understand meteor better in a few days an can create my own reactive context for that. did anyone tried meteor-router? https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router sadfully i have lots of errors if i try to use it :(

Comment: Hey dustin.b, there are several routers for Meteor including the Britto blog package. However after searching for so long I really wanted to try NOT to use external packages for now... and this method works the best for multi page routing.

Comment: @Joc, care to share your dynamic method? Right now I basically use templates within a template, so as the app grows it's still very manageable as each 'page' is within a template with a session variable linked to the backbone router function.

Comment: Jeff, simple really, I use backbone.js but you can prob use any router. And I basically have a wildcard section of the URL path to supply the name of the template for Meteor.render. This can work for nested content too. I answered a question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968808/dynamically-loading-templates-in-meteor-js/12986397#12986397