# Pass data to dynamically created template with meteor

Tags: javascript, dynamic, meteor

Following up on this queston/answer (second answer) [Dynamically loading templates in Meteor.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968808/dynamically-loading-templates-in-meteor-js)

I have set up a helper in the current displayed template and i am returning the template dynamically. This works great.

```
Template.template1.helpers({

    dynamicView: function(){
        return Template['dynamic_template']();
    }
})
```

This ends up showing my html in template 1:

Questions:

1. How do i pass data to this Template as it's being created, can i do something like this:

   Template['dynamic_template'](data1, jsonData2);
2. I want the `dynamicView` helper in template1 to also be dynamic in the sense that it can have a different template based on some other criteria. Can i use a Session here and change the dynamicView return statement to something like this:

   dynamicView: function(){
           return Session.get('dynamicTemplate');
       }

and somewhere else `Session.set('dynamicTemplate', Template['dynamic_template']());` This works, but is it recommended. It's just a string but i am concerned about performance problems and the size of my template being passed reactively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I guess ill have to split my answer up:

With 1.

The templates are compiled handlebars templates so you just need to provide a context to them so the handlebars data can be filled up:

```
data = {name1:value1, name2:value2}
return Template['dynamic_template'](data);
```

So that `{{name1}}` and `{{name2}}` get filled up with `value1` and `value2` respectively.

With 2.

Yes that should work, you can pass off any data that will give off HTML as a result. For a very detailed videocast have a look at the EventedMind screencast on template functions: http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-rendering-template-functions

The template system's use case might not be this exactly. You might want to use [Meteor.render](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_render) instead, but it depends on what you want to do.

Despite the `Session` name, its just a reactive javascript variable so it should be fine with larger strings too to the same that would be used in an ordinary javascript variable

Comment: while i ended up approaching this problem differently, this information is very useful. Thanks for the resources