# Dynamically insert template into table row

Tags: meteor

I have a table with data coming from a collection. When user clicks on a row I want to replace the content of the row with a form to edit the content. What would be the meteor way to do it without jQuery, if possible?

```
<template name="table">
  <table>
    {{#each items}}
    {{> showrow}}
    {{else}}
  </table>
</template>

<template name="showrow">
  <tr>
    <td>{{name}}</td>
  </tr>
</template>

<template name="editrow">
  <tr>
    <form>
      … form html …
    </form>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Essentially, it's about replacing the `showrow`template witn the `editrow` for onw row, I think. Is that a reasonable approach? Any pointers?

Comment: Ok, I think I can change the HTML using the template system with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15092343/233430. But how I do that just for the specific table row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a logical helper

```
<template name="table">
  <table>
    {{#each items}}
        {{#if editmode}}
            {{>editrow}}
        {{else}}        
            {{> showrow}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}         
  </table>
</template>
```

Then in your template helper

```
Template.table.editrow = function() {
    return (this.editmode)
}
```

`this` lets you access the data context that would be in the collection for that particular item in the loop. So if you had a `editmode:true` for that item it would use the edit row instead.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have a session variable which tracks which item is currently being edited. Then you could do something like `return Session.get('editingItemId') === this._id`. You'd then need to set the session variable to `null` on `created` and when you leave the edit mode.

Comment: Thanks. @Akshat, will that automatically change the display if I change editmode in the item?

Comment: I would rather put the item being edited into a session variable, makes more sense to me especially for multiple users.

Comment: Yes it will be reactive too, so if you change editmode it would do that. It depends how you want your logic to work, the above is just an example. Using Session would work well if you want to press something to make it editable and the other if one is universably editable

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was easier than expected. 1:0 for Meteor:

I used the MongoDB `_id` as identifier of each row, in a data attribute: `data-id="{{_id}}"`.

Then I set up a `click` event handler on `<tr>`-elements:

```
Template.booking.events({
    'click tr': function(event, template) {
        Session.set(editBookingId, event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id'));
    }
});
```

A template helper listens to incoming ids and returns true if the ids match:

```
Template.booking.helpers({
    'isEdited': function(id) {
        return Session.get(editBookingId) == id;
    }
});
```

In the template, I decide with `{{#if}}` whether to display the normal row or an edit dialog:

```
{{#if isEdited _id}}EDIT{{/if}}
```

Very little code. Very nice. Thanks for the pointers.