# How do i get an onload function on the body for a specific template using meteor.js?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I'm trying to get the following behavior for a certain template:

```
<body onload="someInitFunction();">
```

Let's say i have the following markup (i'm using mrt router, not iron-router, for {{renderPage}}):

```
// Main Template
<head>
  <title>meteorite-knowviz</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> header}}

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      {{renderPage}}
    </div>
  </div>

  {{> footer}}
</body>
```

That renderPage is the secondTemplate:

```
<template name="secondTemplate">
  {{#if currentUser}}
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item" href="{{render thirdTemplate please...}}">Third Template</a>
        <a class="list-group-item" href="{{render fourthTemplate please...}}">Fourth Template</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    // In this case let's say thirdTemplate gets rendered
    {{render the choice taken above please...}}

  {{/if}}
</template>
```

And within this template, depending on which link was clicked on, (in this case the third) there will finally be a thirdTemplate, which will show a data visualization with some help by a javascript framework, which will be in need of a `<body onload="initFunction();">`in order to display the data:

```
<template name="thirdTemplate">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <h2>THIS!! section needs a "<body onload="initFunction();"> in order to work" ></h2>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <h2>Some other related content here</h2>
  </div>  
</template>
```

To sum up i have three questions:

1a. How could i get the third template to get a `<body onload="initFunction();">`

2a. In which way can i render different templates within the secondTemplate?

2b. Can i use a `{{renderPage}}` within this template even though this template is the renderedPage in the main template or should i do it in some other way?

Comment: What do you mean that a template "get" `body onload`? It's not clear what you're asking about, and you probably are doing something wrong. `body onload` is a function that runs when the page has finished loading, about the same time that `Meteor.startup` procedures are running, and far before any template is rendered. So setting up `body onload` when a template is rendered will do nothing. Most probably you want to move the necessary code to `Template.thirdTemplate.rendered` callback.

Comment: @HubertOG What i mean is that a javascript framework for data visualizations, which will display those visualizations within the hypothetical thirdTemplate, need a initFunction(); on the ´<body>´ of the html page. This i don't know how to do. Perhaps i could just do this with a simple $(document).ready(function(){});?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the `<body onload="initFunction();">` i had to do the following:

First add the following function to a .js file in the client folder:

```
Template.thirdTemplate.rendered = function() { // Template.thirdTemplate.created - also worked.
  $('body').attr({
    onload: 'init();'
  });
}
```

This however got me an error saying that initFunction is not defined. In an standard html page my could work just fine, but in meteor i had to change my function from:

```
function initFunction(){
  //what ever i wished to do 
}
```

To:

```
init = function() {
  //what ever i wished to do
}
```

Regarding the rendering of pages, iron-routing is the way to go since the router add on is not under development any more.

Answer (score 0):

> 1a. How could i get the third template to get a `<body
>   onload="initFunction();">`

You probably want to call initFunction when the third template has been rendered, so just put your call to it in the rendered callback.

```
Template['thirsTemplate'].rendered = function(){
    initFunction()
}
```

> 2a. In which way can i render different templates within the
>   secondTemplate?
>
> 2b. Can i use a {{renderPage}} within this template even though this
>   template is the renderedPage in the main template or should i do it in
>   some other way?

Listen for clicks on the links, and when one happen you manually render the desired template (possible with [Meteor.render](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_render), if you need reactivity) and add it to the right node in the document. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968808/dynamically-loading-templates-in-meteor-js).

It may be possibly to achieve with router (I don't know that package).

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to use is the `created` callback, that will be called each time your template is created, and not the `rendered` callback, that would be called each time a change has caused the template to re-render.

```
Template.thirdTemplate.created = function(){
    initFunction()
}
```

See the documentation for templates for other types of callbacks: http://docs.meteor.com/#templates_api

Comment: If he doesn't need to wait for some template content, he could have placed the call to `initFunction` anywhere, and not necessary in the created callback.

Comment: I can't tell from the question. He could possibly just want to know when the template has been created in order to store some activity in google analytics, or whatever, independently from the content.