# Is there a way to retain events on a template when the template is moved in the DOM?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I ran into an interesting problem. I am using a bootstrap modal in a Meteor template. I've always appended the modal to the body of the page in the past on document ready.

In this case, on Template.name.rendered() is when I'm performing this appendTo('body'), but the events attached to the template no longer work. I partially understand with limited knowledge of meteor why this breaks it.

```
"click #someID": function() {} ... no longer works.
```

I can use standard jQuery to handle it instead of the event functions, but just curious if there's a proper method to handle this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it sounds like you should use [Blaze.render](http://docs.meteor.com/#blaze_render) (or Blaze.renderWithData), which inserts your template instance into the DOM for you. Are you doing that?

Either way, I've created a package for bootstrap 3 that makes it easy to show modals (based on templates). You can use it if you want. https://github.com/PeppeL-G/bootstrap-3-modal

Comment: I wasn't using Blaze.render. I was getting caught up in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968808/dynamically-loading-templates-in-meteor-js   

Your modal package looks awesome. I'll try Blaze.render first but I think the package you created makes things a lot easier... Just want to do it the hard way first to understand. Thank you very much... Will experiment and let you know!

Comment: Thanks for this Peppe. Ended up using your bootstrap package!

Comment: I was having issues with getting my modal to show with onDestroyed but the package referenced solved the issue. I will share this posting in a few other areas where I found others having a similar issue - thank you.