# Is it possible to pass parameters to a dynamic template in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I've seen the various discussions on using a dynamically selected template in Meteor (ex. [here](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/blaze-dynamic-template-includes/), [here](http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/#template-dynamic), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968808/dynamically-loading-templates-in-meteor-js)).

But what if I want to pass a parameter into the dynamic template, that  is:

```
{{> UI.dynamic template=templateName data=dataObj param1=17}}
```

Is there any way to do this?  Essentially, I have three templates, which all take the same parameter.  I want to create a generic template that can dynamically call one of those three, passing along the parameter.

It feels like there should be a way to do it with a helper, but I can't quite figure it out.

-Dov

Comment: And you can't include the parameter information inside of your data context?

Comment: Of course...  It's not in the original context, so I thought about doing it with a helper, but couldn't figure out the syntax for some reason.  At the prompting of your comment, I took another look and it's actually pretty obvious in retrospect.  Will post here in case anyone else gets writers cramp on the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comment from David Weldon, I managed to overcome my writer's block.

Here's the answer for others who manage to end up on this page.

HTML:

```
<head>   
    <title>dynamic test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> generic detailsTemplate="y"}}
</body>

<template name="generic">
    {{> Template.dynamic template=detailsTemplate data=updatedata}}
</template>

<template name="x">
    Here
    edit={{edit}}  - this shows nothing if the data context isn't modified
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
Template.generic.helpers({
  updatedata: function () {
    this.edit = true;
    return this;
  }
});
```

Comment: What's `UI.dynamic` as opposed to `Template.dynamic`?

Comment: @Andy - a mistype... edited question above.  UI.dynamic is the correct syntax

Comment: I just mean, I'm confused, I've only seen `Template.dynamic` in the docs.  If you have a link to `UI.dynamic` documentation handy,  would you mind sharing it?  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting... See http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/New_Blaze_API  I wonder if they both do the same thing?  One issue I've had with the meteor documentation is that it changes often and it's not always clear which version is the most current...  Since template.dynamic is used in the current version docs, I'd assume that probably the preferred one, though I can confirm ui.dynamic does still work in 1.1.0.2