# Meteor: sending info to disconnected templates on clicks

Tags: meteor

I am trying to do a single page app in which a task bar of items is created on clicking some links and when any item on task bar is clicked, it has a corresponding div element in the DOM that must be hidden or shown. So the task bar elements are in separate template and the div elements that task bar manipulates are in separate template. I thought of being able to simply set the display='block' or display='none' using spacebars depending on which task bar item is clicked. but the biggest challenge i am facing is, how to send the ID of the div element to the event handler or helper method?

div elements that need to be hidden or shown.

```
<template name="currentDisplay">
{{#each dispElems}}
    <div id="{{this.elemId}}" display="{{this.dispType}}"></div>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

task bar or menu items

```
<template name="siteHome">
<div id="topBar">
    <div id="navContainer">
        <ul id="navElems">
            <li id="nav1" class="userName">{{> Meteor.userId}}</li>
            <li id="nav0" class="logout">logout</li>
            <li id="nav2" class="nav">Home</li>
            <li id="nav3" class="nav">Files</li>
            <li id="nav4" class="nav">Comm</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="swapArea">
    {{> currentDisplay}}
</div>
</template>
```

I wrote following code but it doesn't work.

```
var navElemsArray = ["nav1"];
var navElemsDispArray = ["disp-nav1"];
var navElemsSettingsArray = ["block"];
var incrementedIndex = 0;

var dispElems = new Mongo.Collection("dispElems");
dispElems.insert({elemId:"nav1", dispId: "disp-nav1", dispType: "block"});

Template.siteHome.events({
'click .logout': function (e, t) {
    Meteor.logout();
},
'click .nav': function (e, t) {
    var elemId = e.currentTarget.id;
    //console.log(navElemsArray);
    console.log(elemId);
    var currentElemIndex = _.indexOf(navElemsArray, elemId);
    console.log(currentElemIndex);
    if(currentElemIndex == -1)
    {
        dispElems.insert({elemId: elemId, dispId: "disp-"+elemId, dispType: "block"});

     /*   navElemsArray.push(elemId);
        navElemsArray.push("disp-"+elemId);
        navElemsSettingsArray.push("block");*/
        incrementedIndex++;
        console.log("INDEX= "+currentElemIndex);
        UI.insert(UI.render(Template.currentDisplay), $("#swapArea").get(0));
    }
    currentNavIndex = currentElemIndex;
    console.log("before loop");
/*        var dE = dispElems.find();
    dE.forEach(function (elem) {
        if(elem.elemId != incrementedIndex) elem.dispType = "none";
    });
*/
    /*
    for(i=0;i<navElemsArray.length;i++)
    {
        console.log("Setting for "+i);
        if(i == incrementedIndex)
        {
            console.log("Setting block for "+i);
            navElemsSettingsArray[i] = "block";
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Setting none for "+i);
            navElemsSettingsArray[i] = "none";
        }
    }*/
}
}
});
```

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
I would suggest you to use
http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.2.0/docs/components/#nav-tabs
for handling tabs functionality.
```

To send id to the template you can use data argument ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968808/dynamically-loading-templates-in-meteor-js/23351293#23351293)):

```
<div id="swapArea">
    {{>  Template.dynamic template=currentDisplay data = myDataHelper}}
</div>
```

Have a variable id like

```
    var incrementedIndex = 0;
    var elemId;

Template.siteHome.events({
        'click .nav': function (e, t) {
           elemId = e.currentTarget.id;
           .....
        }
    });

Template.siteHome.helpers({
     myDataHelper: function () {
          return elemID;
     }
});
```

Then get the id in currentDisplay template :

```
Template.currentDisplay.rendered = function () {
     var id = this.data;
}
```

Comment: Agree, nav-tabs do all this for you.

Comment: Thanks! but there is a problem with that. I don't want tabs. Is it possible to CSS-out the tabs while using the navigation feature?

Comment: I read a bit more about it. Is it possible to keep switching between divs in swapArea that i have? how do i do that? like one div for Home, another for Messages and while Home is active hide all other navigation controlled divs...