# How to load partial in Meteor using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, templates, meteor, partial, meteor-blaze

I have this inside my **application.html** file:

```
<head>
    ...
</head>

<body>
    {{> nav2}}
        {{> home}}
    {{> footer}}
</body>
```

And this is my **nav2.html**:

```
<template name="nav2">
  ...
  <div id="top_nav_sub_menus"></div>
  ...
</template>
```

I try to load 2 different nav items inside my nav2 targeting the `top_nav_sub_menus` element. One is for desktop, one is for mobile.

**desktop_nav.html**

```
<template name="desktop_nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="benefits">X</a>
      <ul class="menu vertical benefits_children">
        <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
</template>
```

**mobile_nav.html**

```
<template name="mobile_nav">
    <li><a href="#" id="benefits">X</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
</template>
```

Since I'm using [detectmobilebrowser.js](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/), I try to do it like this inside my **application.js**:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  $(function(){
    if ($.browser.mobile) {
      $("#top_nav_sub_menus").html(Meteor.render(mobile_nav));
    } else {
      $("#top_nav_sub_menus").html(Meteor.render(desktop_nav));      
    }
  })
}
```

But it doesn't work.

**What I've tried and doesn't work**:

1 - `Blaze.render(mobile_nav, "#top_nav_sub_menus")`

2 - Using [jquery-meteor-blaze](https://github.com/eface2face/jquery-meteor-blaze) with this syntax:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

      Template.home.onRendered(function () {
        if($.browser.mobile) {
          $("#top_nav_sub_menus")
            .blaze(template['mobile_nav'])
            .render();
        }
      });

      $(function(){
      ...
      })
    }
```

What am I missing here?

**Note**:

This is my tree view of my directory:

```
├── application.css.scss
├── application.html
├── application.js
├── client
│   ├── javascripts
│   │   ├── detectmobilebrowser.js
│   │   └── jquery-meteor-blaze.js
│   ├── stylesheets
│   │   ├── base.css.scss
│   │   ├── footer.css.scss
│   │   ├── home.css.scss
│   │   ├── nav.css.scss
│   └── views
│       ├── home.html
│       └── layouts
│           ├── desktop_nav.html
│           ├── footer.html
│           ├── mobile_nav.html
│           ├── nav.html
│           └── nav2.html
└── public
    ├── fonts
    │   └── ...
    └── images
        └── ...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968808/dynamically-loading-templates-in-meteor-js

Comment: @Abhi I tried it before posting this question. Doesn't work for me.

Comment: are you writing {{> whatever_nav}} in nav2?

Comment: I do it like this: `$("#top_nav_sub_menus").html({{> Template.dynamic template=mobile_nav }})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to do it.

I put this in my **application.js** file:

```
  Template.nav2.helpers({
    isMobile: function(){
      if ($.browser.mobile){
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

And this inside my **nav2.html** file:

```
{{#if isMobile}}
  {{> mobile_nav}}
{{else}}
  {{> desktop_nav}}
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=templateFinder }}


Template.nav2.helpers({
templateFinder: function(){

 if ($.browser.mobile){
return mobile_nav; }
else{
return desktop_nav; }

}
});
```

Comment: I get this error `Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: mobile_nav is not defined`